# How to calculate aggregated conditional prepayment rates

Tags: mbs

I understand that the formula for loan-level CPR is:

$$
CPR = 1 - ( 1 - SMM)^{12} 
$$
where
$$
 SMM = \frac{Prepaid monthly balance}{Scheduled Blance}
$$

But Im not too sure how the formula changes when aggregating the loan-level data to a cohort-level. Does the formula for $SMM$ then become as follows, where the sum is calculated across all the loans that fall into that cohort:

$$
 SMM = \frac{sum_{Prepaid monthly balance}}{sum_{Scheduled Blance}}
$$

And if this second equation for $SMM$ is correct, how does the $SMM$ equation go from 1 to 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation formula for SMM is correct. The SMM for the cohort can be defined to the weighted-average SMMs of the individual loans (in the cohort), where the weights are the scheduled balances of the individual loans. A little bit of algebra shows that this is the same as your expression for the SMM of the cohort:

\begin{align*}
\mbox{SMM}_{\mbox{Port}} &= \frac{\sum_i (\mbox{sched}_i - \mbox{curr}_i)}{\sum_i \mbox{sched}_i} \\
&= \sum_i \frac{1}{\sum_i \mbox{sched}_i} \frac{\mbox{sched}_i}{\mbox{sched}_i}(\mbox{sched}_i - \mbox{curr}_i) \\
&= \sum_i \frac{\mbox{sched}_i}{\sum_i \mbox{sched}_i} \mbox{SMM}_i
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps. I wanted to also ask (and this may be a pretty silly question, but I would like to understand), how do we get from $$CPR = 1 - ( 1 - SMM)^{12}$$ at the loan-level to $$\mbox{CPR}_{\mbox{Port}} = 1 - ( 1 - \mbox{SMM}_{\mbox{Port}})^{12}$$ at the portfolio-level? Can the summation really be taken through the equation to just act on $SMM$? Thanks again

Comment: Taking your question at face value, you would convert your individual CPRs to individual SMMs, take weighted-averages as above to get a portfolio SMM, and then convert to a portfolio CPR. There's no direct formula that connects portfolio CPR to the individual CPRs because of the non-linear relationship between CPR and SMM.

Comment: Great, that explains it.